# What is the right way to create project structure in pycharm?

Tags: python, package, pycharm

I'm new to python and I don't know how to organize the project structure in the right way, so all auto imports would work in pycharm.

That's my current structure.

[image]

In PublisherSubscriberTest pycharm generated this import

```
from Rabbit.RabbitReceiver import RabbitReceiver
from Rabbit.RabbitSender import RabbitSender
```

But it's not working. That's the output.

> ImportError: No module named Rabbit.RabbitReceiver

What have I done wrong?

I'm more familiar with java. And for example in java I would just create package with some classes and then I would be able to import them anywhere in my project. AFAIK it's not the same with python somehow.

Could someone explain this to me?

EDIT1:
Yes, I know about sys.path.append. I used to do it that way, but It seemed strange to me and i want to be able to do it without it.

Comment: Can you paste your current project structure(Directories and files)?

Comment: python 2 or python 3?

Comment: Python 2.7. Well, my project structure is in screenshot. What else do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import sys, os.path

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
from Rabbit.RabbitReceiver import RabbitReceiver
from Rabbit.RabbitSender import RabbitSender
```

If you don't want to modify `sys.path`, the only way is to add `-m` flag when you run it

```
python -m messaging_system.tests.PublisherSubscriberTest
```

see [How to fix "Attempted relative import in non-package" even with __init__.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py)

### edit

OK, finally I found an ultimate answer: **[Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/python-relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)**

I suggest you read that post carefully, from which I learned a lot.

In short, if you want to do this, you have to add `path-to-Rabbit` to `sys.path`.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I know about that. That's what I used to do. I consider this as inconvinient and whant to be able import packages in my project without appending them is sys.path.

Comment: It's not working with -m option. Still the same import error.

Comment: @user1685095 what do you think?

Comment: Well, basically I don't need relative imports at all.
I actually ended up with something like this

python -m unittest tests.ArchiveTest

Comment: @user1685095 I'm glad you get it resolved. Maybe it's better to write down what you want to achieve next time. For your original question, that should be enough information.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. What  I've actually wanted was just a part of my question.