# how to make a file act as a python module

Tags: python

I want to make a file that is consisted of 3 python programs.
but, when I want to access one of the there files from one of them, it cant find the folder.

I made a **init** python file in it so python can recognize it as a module

my folder struct:

```
dlgo/
        __init__.py
        goboard_slow.py
        gotypes.py
```

my goboard_slow:

```
from dlgo.gotypes import player
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asus\Desktop\dlgo\goboard_slow.py", line 2, in <module>
    from dlgo.gotypes import player
ImportError: No module named 'dlgo'
```

Comment: You're already inside that module; see e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: You can take Misieq's answer - however, make sure your $PYTHONPATH is set up correctly (e.g. if you're working with Pycharm, it may be set to the root). To check your $PYTHONPATH you can `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access as below:

```
from dlgo.gotypes import players
```

See [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#id5) more info on "Guido's decision" on imports in python 3 and complete example on how to import in python 3.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try `from (filename) import (functionname)`

Answer (score 0):

Tl;dr:

```
from gotypes.py import player
```

when you specify path to a file, interpreter starts looking for it inside same folder, unless you give it path from main dirrectory like '/' or 'C:\'

Comment: Your .py looks rather unconventional. It should work without the .file type

Answer (score 0):

You can import a py file with the following statement:

```py
# Other import
import os
import sys

if './dlgo' not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, './dlgo')
from dlgo.gotypes import player
```

**NOTE:**
For IDE like PyCharm, you can specify the import path using the Project Structure setting tab (CTRL+ALT+S)

***Helpful stack overflow questions*** [maybe off topic]:
[What is the right way to create project structure in pycharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21136241/what-is-the-right-way-to-create-project-structure-in-pycharm)

***Manage import with PyCharm documentation:***
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-project-structure.html

Comment: Have a try with '../dlgo'. Seems that your are alredy into that folder